# How to show one decimal place (Without rounding) and show .0 for whole numbers?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a nice way to show show decimal numbers with one decimal place all the time but without rounding? So you have the following numbers:

```
3.55
3.5
3
```

and I want them to show

```
3.5
3.5
3.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Math.floor` instead.

```
pad(Math.floor(num * 10) / 10);
```

where `pad` adds `.0` if it needs to.

Keep in mind that `Math.round` is probably better. Since `3.55` should be `3.6`.

Answer (score 2):

you can also use the `toFixed()` method, though this converts the float to a string.

```
var float = 3.55

float.toFixed(1);
```

This will round but rounds down a decimal of 0.5 in any position

Comment: Poor choice of variable name. JavaScript doesn't actually make it a float if you do it like this.

Comment: In an example where you declare a float it makes sense... I did say it typecasts it to a string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (where x is your float):

```
function format_float(float x )
 {
   if ((x).tostring().contains(".") ) 
   {return parseFloat((x).tostring().Substring(0,indexof(".")+1)) ;}
   else 
   {return x.toFixed(1);}
 }
```

Comment: toFixed does rounding, the OP wants truncation.

Comment: x.toFixed(1) is going to be executed only on non decimal numbers(integers) . and the floats are going to be returned untouched.

Comment: That isn't what the OP wants, "without rounding" means truncation in this case. The question is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: Then instead of returning x he can return [parseFloat((x).tostring().Substring(0,indexof(".")+1)) ]

Answer (score 0):

To remove the need for a pad function:

```
function toOnePlace(n) {
  n = ('' + n).split('.');
  return n[0] + '.' + (n[1]? n[1].charAt(0) : 0);
}
```